# Swiftlint unable to open configuration file

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, swiftlint

I installed **swiftlint** through **brew**

```
brew install swiftlint
```

verified successfull installation through

```
swiftlint --version
0.50.1
```

Added script to project

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin"
if which swiftlint >/dev/null; then
  echo "SwiftLint started"
  swiftlint
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Also i have:
root project: 
-> .swiftlint.yml

When i'm trying to build project I'm getting

[image: Swiftlint error message]

Tried also 
`swiftlint lint --config project/.swiftlint.yml`

**Update:**
After several mac restarts somehow after time it is **fixed**

Comment: No error when using swiftlint from the command line for the project?

Comment: No. It goes fine. "Done linting! Found xy violations, xy serious in xy files."

Comment: So it must be some other kind of settings file then. Maybe this is an Xcode issue so you might want to try the usual things, clean the build folder, delete derived data, restart Xcode.

Comment: tried. Also restart macbook

Comment: in your script you are not specifying the config file, just `swiftlint`, in your command line you do (yes, this is the right use, but also the key difference). So for starters print out your current directory in the script (e.g. add `pwd` over  `if which swiftlint` line). Make sure your current dir is the directory where .swiftlint.yml is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: After several mac restarts somehow after time it is **fixed**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't have read permission for the swiftlint.yml in my Swift Package. I solved it by adding the swiftlint.yml file to the sources list in my Target.